# ComboBox reflection in c#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have this code:

```
typeof(ComboBox).GetProperty("SelectedItem").SetValue("comboBox1", "", null);
```

It is not working. Here is the error:

> "Object does not match target type"

What is wrong?

Update:

I have the name of my object (comboBox in string. like:

```
string []s = new s[3];
s[0]="comboBox0"; 
s[1]="comboBox1"; 
s[2]="comboBox2";
```

I want to set a value to the property SelectedItem to my comboBox `s[i]`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291.aspx) need to have `ComboBox` object, not string "comboBox1". I believe you have a ComboxBox object in your application, assume:

```
ComboBox comboBox1 = ....;
```

So you can call:

```
typeof(ComboBox).GetProperty("SelectedItem")
                .SetValue(comboBox1, "", null);
```

If you use .NET 4.5, you can get rid of the last input:

```
typeof(ComboBox).GetProperty("SelectedItem")
                .SetValue(comboBox1, "");
```

**Edit**: based on your comment, you don't need to use reflection, below is you can get combox1 if only knowing the name:

```
var comboBox1 = Controls.OfType<ComboBox>()
                      .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Combobox1");

comboBox1.SelectedItem = "";
```

Comment: @Chanipoz: don't understand, could you explain more?

Comment: I have a string with the name of the comboBox like: s="comboBox1", how can I set a value to it?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument that you send to `PropertyInfo.SetValue` is the object that you want to set value. For example, if you named your ComboBox object to `comboBox1` then you have to change from `SetValue("comboBox1", "", null);` to `SetValue(comboBox1, "", null);`

You can read more on [PropertyInfo.SetValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The `SetValue` method requires 3 parameters, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the first parameter is the instance object, the second is the value and the third is the index for indexed properties, set to null if not used.

so

```
var box = <method to get combobox1>;
typeof(ComboBox).GetProperty("SelectedItem").SetValue(box,"",null);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the form where your ComboBoxes are put, add this method:

```
public void SetComboBoxValue(string comboBoxName, string value)
{
    ComboBox foundCombo = Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == comboBoxName) as ComboBox;
    if (foundCombo == null)
        return;
    foundCombo.SelectedItem = value;
}
```